# JQuery efficient way to $("#foo > .row") (direct child)

Tags: jquery, performance

I use this JQuery-Selector:

```
$("#foo > .row")
```

PHPStrom shows me *Inefficient jquery selector*.

Whats the more efficient way to select only direct childs of one ID?

Comment: While the linked answer isn't an exact duplicate, it does also cover this scenario specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the element by id, then get it's children.

```
$("#foo").children()
```

This is more efficient because it first uses `document.getElementById`, then it gets the element's childNodes that are elements, skipping the selector engine completely.

Comment: +1 Verified this in Chrome 34 and IE 11 [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/jquery-direct-child-selector-example)...

Comment: leaving this here since the answers in the linked question don't specifically use this example